# Can't upload files to webserver from website with js/php

Tags: javascript, php, html, upload, webserver

Im hosting my website on my raspberry pi. Im trying to build a website, which gives the option to upload pictures to my webserver. The structure goes like. [www.URL.de/projects/nameOfTheProjects/uploads](http://www.URL.de/projects/nameOfTheProjects/uploads).

When I run the website with XAMPP it works but from my webserver it doesn't.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
//Move files to directory
$targetPath = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["inpFile"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inpFile"]["tmp_name"], $targetPath);
?>
```

---

```
<form id="myForm">
            <input type="file" id="inpFile"><br><br>
            <button type="submit">UPLOAD</button>
        </form>                        
    </center>
    <script>
        const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");

        myForm.addEventListener("submit", e =>{
            e.preventDefault();

            const endpoint = "upload.php"; 
            const formData = new FormData();

            // console.log(inpFile.files);

            formData.append("inpFile", inpFile.files[0]);

            //endpoin
            fetch(endpoint, {                    
                method:  "post",
                body: formData,
                console: console.log("DONE")                    
            }).catch(console.error);

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The tutorial i followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cei2Ch683q0

Comment: Try using a full path to the `upload` directory like `dirname(__FILE__). "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["inpFile"]["name"]); `

Comment: What's the error? view in error log or turn on error message and show us here. Also check on correct path and permission.

Comment: @vee the problem is there is no error, that’s why I’m so confused

Comment: @zimorok didnt work :(